# Can't remove http header "X-AspNetMvc-Version"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to remove the Http header `X-AspNetMvc-Version`. I added this in `Global.asax`:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```

but it doesn't work. In Firefox I can see `X-AspNetMvc-Version: "5.1"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418557/how-to-remove-asp-net-mvc-default-http-headers

Comment: there is no answer to my question

Comment: What happens if you retrieve `MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader` later on? Is it still set to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to just stick this into your Global.asax.cs:

```
MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have anything configured in the HTTP response headers in IIS.

Comment: Have a one response : X-Powered-By