# Default HTTP Headers IIS 7 'MvcHandler' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config, global-asax

Here is my code in Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">



    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
       Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
       Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
       Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");

    }


</script>
```

I use this code too

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```

**but I received this error :
The name 'MvcHandler' does not exist in the current context**

in my Web config I use this code

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

     <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
      <clear />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>

    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>

    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />

                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>




 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">     
   </modules>    
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

How can I remove MVC Default HTTP Headers ?
I can't remove the HTTP Header and I received one error in this line The name 'MvcHandler' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove ASP.Net MVC Default HTTP Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418557/how-to-remove-asp-net-mvc-default-http-headers)

Comment: @Fran I updated the codes and I am so new in mvc I need to add framework or ?

Comment: @Fran its not duplicate  here is my error The name 'MvcHandler' does not exist in the current context

Comment: MvcHandler lives in System.Web.Mvc.  You need to include System.Web.Mvc in your .asax file if you are going to write you handlers in the asax and not the .cs file.  Why don't you have a codebehind for the Global.asax?  Those are created when the project is created.