# Asp.Net MVC5 - how to remove ,,Server" header from static elements response (e.g svg files)

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-5, response-headers

I'm trying to remove Server information from headers response in asp.net mvc5 application. I added following code to application, which take care for most of server responses:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

The problem which I'm trying to get rid, is when server return static data like icons for img elements, for example I have following code:

```
 <img src="~/Content/images/my_super_logo.svg" alt="super-app"/>
```

Which generate and return me following response from server:

Request url: http://localhost:51989/Content/images/my_super_logo.svg
Response headers: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

I'm looking for any solution which allows me to get control of server headers when I'm getting static data. Is there something other which I can filter in Global.asax.cs file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418557/

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put some middleware in the stack of responses from asp.net that runs after the static file hosting, but I'm not sure that this is practical - getting it in the right place when ASP.NET wants to do things its way is tricky, and adding middleware is not so easy.

But, you can instead run Kestrel on the web and hide it behind [another webserver passing requests to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (for security if nothing else). If you use nginx, you can remove headers from the response [easily](https://gist.github.com/aamishbaloch/1031e7490d7d57d55baff57fce8d2997), and if you set the right header ([x-accel-redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/)) you can also serve these static files via nginx directly.